# npm run watch removes content in mix.manifest.json

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm, laravel-mix, manifest.json

Please help. I am developing a project with Laravel and Vuejs. When I do **npm  run watch**, contect is removed from mix.manifest.json and I see only 2 lines.

**This is my modified mix.manifest.json**

```js
{
    "/js/app.js": "/js/app.js",
    "/css/app.css": "/css/app.css",
    "/frontend/custom/custom.css": "/frontend/custom/custom.css",
    "/css/lobibox.min.css":"/css/lobibox.min.css",
    "/css/simplebar.css": "/css/simplebar.css",
    "/css/perfect-scrollbar.css": "/css/perfect-scrollbar.css",
    "/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js": "/frontend/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
    "/frontend/js/jquery.min.js": "/frontend/js/jquery.min.js",
    "/frontend/js/pace.min.js": "/frontend/js/pace.min.js",
    "/frontend/js/app.js": "/frontend/js/app.js",
    "/frontend/js/process.js":"/frontend/js/process.js",
    "/frontend/plugins/perfect-scrollbar/js/perfect-scrollbar.js": "/frontend/plugins/perfect-scrollbar/js/perfect-scrollbar.js",
    "/js/lobibox.min.js":"/js/lobibox.min.js",
    "/js/notifications.min.js":"/js/notifications.min.js",
    "/frontend/plugins/notifications/js/notification-custom-script.js":"/frontend/plugins/notifications/js/notification-custom-script.js"
}
```

This is what I see when I run **npm run watch**

```js
{
    "/js/app.js": "/js/app.js",
    "/css/app.css": "/css/app.css"
}
```

Here is Webpack.mix.js

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.js('resources/js/app.js','public/js')
.sass('resources/sass/app.scss','public/css').sourceMaps();
```

Any one who can help

Comment: So that is how it is supposed to work. You have two calls in your `webpack.mix.js` one for compiling `app.js` and another for compiling `app.scss` hence two files are created and `mix.manifest.json` is updated accordingly

Comment: How do I include those others calls regarding my question?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need entries for external libraries like `jquery.min.js` in `mix.manifest.json`.

Entries in`mix.manifest.json` file serve as lookup table for when using `mix()` helper in blade views especially when versioning.

For external libraries - js or css files - which you will not be compiling you don't need to have them in `mix.manifest.json` you don't need to use `mix()` helper for these kind of files - you can use `asset()` helper if you want for these files.

If you want to copy such files you can use [Laravel Mix Docs - Copy utilities](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/copying-files)

Or if you want to bundle all external dependencies in to a single bundle, you can make use of [Laravel Mix Docs - Concatenation & Minification utilities](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/concatenation-and-minification)